# Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type model

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to load data to RecycleView from Firebase. But I get convert error.

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type uk.co.stableweb.kithunugee.model.Hymn
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzd(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)  
     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:147)
     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:136)
     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:176)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5956)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1192)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5956)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5956)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5956)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5956)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5956)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2671)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18850)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2107)
```

This is how I load data from RecycleView.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Hymn, HymnHolder>(Hymn.class, R.layout.hymn_row, HymnHolder.class, ref) {
       @Override
       protected void populateViewHolder(HymnHolder viewHolder, Hymn hymn, int position) {
              viewHolder.setTitle(hymn.getTitle());
              viewHolder.setIndex(String.valueOf(hymn.getIndex()));
      }
};

// Scroll to bottom on new messages
mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
       @Override
       public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
              mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount());
       }
});

recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

And my ViewHolder class is,

```
public class HymnHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public HymnHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        TextView field = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        field.setText(name);
    }

    public void setIndex(String index) {
        TextView field = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.index);
        field.setText(index);
    }
}
```

And this is my model.

```
public class Hymn {
    private int index;
    private String title;
    private String content;

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Here is the structure of my Firebase database.

[image]

I refered [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) Firebase UI tutorial. There were few previous questions regarding this problem, but it's not clear to me. If you have any hint on this issue, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Is there more to this error? E.g. where it occurs?

Comment: I don't think so, anyway I added full error code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am afraid I cannot deduce anything from either the code nor the bloody error log. Can you try to run in debug mode, put a lot of breakpoints and follow them until you know **for sure** which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: Ok, I will try that as well. Thanks!

Comment: After you've done that, Edit the question stating what line causes the error, and write the comment and @mention me. Good luck.

Comment: I am not familiar with Firebase, but on the structure you are showing, it looks like that "geethika" is returning an array (indexes 1, 2 ) and your are expecting an object Hymn.

Comment: You're reading one level too high in the tree. From your data structure it seems you want `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("geethika");` Under that node each child seems to match your `Hymn` class.

Answer (score 2):

Change your database reference

**old code**

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

**new code**

```
 mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("geethik‌​a");
```